# onClick remove borders and on next click add them again CSS,Preact

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, preact

Hello using a table kind of like this

https://jsfiddle.net/vw19pbfo/24/

how could i make a trigger `onClick` that removes borders on first click and on second click add them back but that should only happen on the row that is being clicked on and not affect the other. I have tried to have a conditional css on the first and last `<td>` but that affected every border but i only want to affect the clicked one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeBorders(e){
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  target.parentElement.classList.toggle('without-border');
};
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewincontact/su86fhxo/9/

Changes:

1) to css:

```
.my-table-row.without-border td {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

2) to html:

```
onclick=removeBorders(event) instead  onClick=this.removeBorders()
```

Comment: Do you know which type i should use event as in typescript? cause if i use function removeBorders(e: Event) it says parentElement does not exist on type EventTarget. But this is exactly what i am after

Comment: I got it working! Thanks! One last question if you know it. is there a way that say i pressed first row so no borders and when i press second row i want first row to have borders again and no borders on second. So all but the latest clicked row have border-radius still

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to check the `<td>` element's parent and add/remove a custom class, like so:

```
function removeBorders(e) {
    var row = e.parentElement;

    if (row.className.indexOf("has-borders") === -1) {
        row.classList.add("has-borders");
    } else {
        row.classList.remove("has-borders");
    }
};
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d380sjrh/

I also changed `onClick=this.removeBorders()` to `onclick="removeBorders(this);"`.

Comment: somewere close to what i am looking for. but the borders i want to remove is the rounded borders that are on the tds the first and last td so they become like border:0 and then back to radius on second click

Comment: "somewere close to what i am looking for" - then you should be more specific in your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4qdstec7/

Use React's state to set and unset the selected class.

```
const Row = ({ children }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const onClick = e => setSelected(!selected);

  return (
    <tr
      className={selected && 'selected'}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </tr>
  )
}
```

Developing in React requires a shift in thinking from traditional web development. Please take some time to read this [excellent post](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) from the React team.